# Header is transparent at the top

Tags: html, css

I'm having a lot of trouble stopping my header from going transparent whilst scrolling down the page. I'm not sure what is causing it (I used a template), but you can view the code here:

https://github.com/IF-Apps/IF-Charts

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang=""> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!--<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">-->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title>IF-Charts - Charts and Plates for Flight Simulation</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fancybox.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flexslider.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/queries.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/etline-font.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/animate.css/animate.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3-respond-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
</head>
<body id="top">
    <!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <p class="browserupgrade">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->
    <section class="hero">
        <section class="navigation">
            <header>
                <div class="header-content">

                    <div class="header-nav">
                        <nav>
                            <ul class="primary-nav">
                            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="ifcharts.html">IF-Charts</a></li>
                                <li><a href="learnmore.html">Learn More</a></li>
                                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                    <div class="navicon">
                        <a class="nav-toggle" href="#"><span></span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
        </section>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                    <div class="hero-content text-center">
                        <h1>IF-Charts</h1>
                        <p class="intro">Plan your flight with plates.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
            <section class="features section-padding" id="features">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="feature-list">
                        <h3>Plan your flight</h3>
                        <p>Select the airport you would like charts for. Want to learn how to use charts? Check out the <a href="tutorial.html">tutorial</a>. PLEASE NOTE THAT THESE CHARTS ARE NOT FOR OPERATIONAL USE!</p>
                        <br>
                        <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/IF-Charts-1233474450057832/" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div> <br> <br>
                        <br>

    <div align="center">
      <h2>Please choose:</h2>
      <br />

          <span>

            <a href="charts_depart.html"><img src="img/takeoff-the-plane.png" alt="Departures" style="width:80px;height:80px;border:0;"></a>

            <a href="charts_arrive.html"><img src="img/plane-landing.png" alt="Arrivals" style="width:80px;height:80px;border:0;"></a>

          </span>
       <p>View all charts <a href="ifcharts-old.html">here</a>.
    </div>
           </section>
    <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <div class="footer-links">
                        <a href="https://github.com/GiacomoLaw/IF-Charts/blob/master/LICENSE">Licence</a> | <p><p>By Giacomo Lawrance.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="bower_components/retina.js/dist/retina.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/classie/classie.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/jquery-waypoints/lib/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID. -->
    <script>
    (function(b,o,i,l,e,r){b.GoogleAnalyticsObject=l;b[l]||(b[l]=
    function(){(b[l].q=b[l].q||[]).push(arguments)});b[l].l=+new Date;
    e=o.createElement(i);r=o.getElementsByTagName(i)[0];
    e.src='//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js';
    r.parentNode.insertBefore(e,r)}(window,document,'script','ga'));
    ga('create','UA-XXXXX-X','auto');ga('send','pageview');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I think it has to do with the CSS, but I am not sure.

The problem is that when at the top, the menu items cannot be seen. I just want the header to stay black. You can see the problem here:

https://if-charts.000webhostapp.com/

Comment: We need to view the code here ... the relevant code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your scripts.js file there is a function that adds or removes several things on scroll.

```
/***************** Header BG Scroll ******************/

    $(function() {
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

            if (scroll >= 20) {
                $('section.navigation').addClass('fixed');
                $('header').css({
                    "border-bottom": "none",
                    "padding": "35px 0"
                });
                $('header .member-actions').css({
                    "top": "26px",
                });
                $('header .navicon').css({
                    "top": "34px",
                });
            } else {
                $('section.navigation').removeClass('fixed');
                $('header').css({
                    "border-bottom": "solid 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)",
                    "padding": "50px 0"
                });
                $('header .member-actions').css({
                    "top": "41px",
                });
                $('header .navicon').css({
                    "top": "48px",
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

---

Remove this function entirely.

Change

```
<section class="navigation">
```

To

```
<section class="navigation fixed">
```

---

If you want to use the other properties as well add them to the following classes in the CSS file.

```
header {
  border-bottom: none;
  padding: 35px 0;
}

header .member-actions {
  top: 26px;
}

header .navicon {
  top: 34px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a background color to the navigation.

```
.navigation {
    background: #232731;
}
```